# accessing the value of a dictionary from a tuple

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples, networkx

I am working with networkx and I need to sort the edges based on the value of the weights.
the edges come in the form of a list of tuples with the weight as a dictionary, the third element of the tuple:

```
G.edges = [(u, v, {'weight' = value})]
```

I am trying to use

```
sorted(G.edges(data = True), key= lambda x: x[2].values())
```

but I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'.
```

Could you pleas help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: cast the dict_values object to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you'd want the actual value not all the dict_values.

```py
sorted(G.edges(data = True), key=lambda x: x[2].get("weight", 0))
```

The relevance of the second argument to `get` is that by default `dict.get` returns `None` for keys that don't exist in the dictionary, so you'd risk (maybe) raising an exception for indexing with a NoneType. This simply sets the weight sort value to 0 in those cases.